# how to compare two table and get changed data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one query like this: this query taking data from T_Order_Header

```
select F_Exhibitor,F_Stand
from T_Order_Header
where F_Exhibition='12004'

output
--------
F_exhibitor   F_stand
2477           C1
2488           C2
2489           C3
```

i have another query like this: this is taking from T_ExhibitorLocation

```
 select F_ExhibitorCode,F_Stand
 from T_ExhibitorLocation
 where F_ExhibitionCode='12004' 

output
--------
F_ExhibitorCode   F_stand
2477              C1
2488              c2
2489              B1
```

T_order_header table F_Exhibitor and T_exhibtor location F_ExhibitorCode is same .

I want to compare both table and check any stand no changed. If any stand no changed I want to show that.

Comment: Use `(query1) INTERSECT (query2)` to show record that are the same from both queries

Comment: if i use this what out put i will get sir

Comment: You will get  `2477           C1
2488           C2`, Just try `select F_Exhibitor,F_Stand
from T_Order_Header
where F_Exhibition='12004' INTERSECT select F_ExhibitorCode,F_Stand
 from T_ExhibitorLocation
 where F_ExhibitionCode='12004' `

Comment: Try this query by yourself, INTERSECT of set (A, B, C) and  (B, C, D) is (B, C)

Comment: What output you are expecting? Probably you should show some null values as well with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a computed column indicating whether the values are equal or should be checked, you could make use of [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) like this:

```
SELECT 
 o.F_Exhibitor,
 o.F_Stand AS OrderHeaderStand, 
 e.F_Stand AS ExhibitorLocationStand,
 CASE 
   WHEN o.F_Stand = e.F_Stand THEN 'Equal'
   WHEN o.F_Stand IS NULL AND e.F_Stand IS NULL THEN 'Equal'
   ELSE 'Check'
 END AS Equal
FROM T_Order_Header o
  INNER JOIN T_ExhibitorLocation e
    ON o.F_exhibitor= e.F_ExhibitorCode
WHERE o.F_Exhibition='12004'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select toh.F_Exhibitor,toh.F_Stand
from T_Order_Header toh
INNER JOIN T_ExhibitorLocation tel
ON toh.F_exhibitor= tel.F_ExhibitorCode
WHERE toh.F_stand = tel.F_stand
AND toh.F_Exhibition='12004'
```

Comment: Ambiguous column name 'F_Stand'.

Comment: this is getting both are matching ?

Comment: You will get 2477 C1 2488 C2

Comment: ok ..i have query like this:UPDATE o SET o.F_Stand = e.F_Stand FROM t_order_header o 
INNER JOIN T_ExhibitorLocation e ON e.F_ExhibitorCode = o.F_Exhibitor and
 o.F_Exhibition= '12004'

Comment: but this is not updating if i have one row in T_order_header Table like this F_Exhibitor 2486 and F_stand null

Comment: in this case you have to use left join